# Modifying mouse-over effect of hyperlink CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Guys so I was working on a nav menu for a wordpress theme but I have some issues.

Here's the site:
http://tasmaniandevilz.com/mima/

What I need to do is have that bottom border (underline) hover effect going on on the primary menu and ***stay there*** as I move to the secondary menu that appears. 
Then on the secondary menu links, that underlining ***should not*** be there.

With a 'normal' website I don't have any problems achieving this, but since I am dynamically assigning the menu links in wordpress (and using only one class for the whole nav) I have some trouble here.
Here's the code:

```
<nav class="bordermenu">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
            );  
            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
        </nav>



    .bordermenu ul li a{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
-webkit-transition: .1s all linear;
-moz-transition: .1s all linear;
-o-transition: .1s all linear;
transition: .1s all linear;
}


.bordermenu ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

How would you go about this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.menu-menu-container ul li > ul li:hover 
{
    border: 0;
}

.menu li:hover 
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Remove:

```
.bordermenu ul li a:hover
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

the above to the stylesheet should work. It will only remove the underline from the sub menu links

Comment: Alright, that works! Thank you. And what about the border staying there? As I've done here.. http://jsfiddle.net/c4qjb3wp/4/

Comment: finally works just as it should! Although your code didn't work that much and I had to do quite some editing. Seems like my thinking is better late at night :D. I learned to use the default WP classes from you. Thanks for help.